# Can't get curl working in wamp

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I'm a complete PHP/wamp noob but am just trying to get a simple bit of code to work. I'm using a library to help me out with OAuth for Twitter, and have been writing and testing my code with wamp on Windows.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

include 'tmhOAuth.php';
include 'tmhUtilities.php';

$tweet_text = 'Test Tweet. If you can see this, my PHP code is working! Yay';
echo "Posting...\n";
$result = post_tweet($tweet_text);
echo "Response code: " . $result . "\n";

function post_tweet($tweet_text) {

    $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
        'consumer_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        'consumer_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'user_token' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'user_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    ));

    $connection->request('POST',
        $connection->url('1/statuses/update'),
        array('status' => $tweet_text));

    return $connection->response['code'];
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

And the error message I get:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\PHP\tmhOAuth.php on line 581
tmhOAuth is one of the library files I'm using.

After a quick Google, I followed this tutorial:
http://www.phpmind.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp/
I found php.ini in both the apache and php folders, and uncommented the lines about curl. I also replaced php_curl.dll in the ext folder with a different version  of the file as instructed by another tutorial I found.

Please help

Comment: Recheck everything: Is your PHP extension path correctly defined? Did you tried to restart WAMP? Did you try the steps described here: http://www.technoreaders.com/2009/07/26/curl-on-wamp/ ?

Comment: Can you create a file in your webserver to display phpinfo? `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Search for curl to see if it exists and is enabled in your phpinfo display. If it's not, the curl module is not enabled

Comment: It seems cURL extension is not properly installed. You can verify proper installation via phpinfo()

Comment: I can't find curl in the php info file so guessing it's not enabled...

Answer (score 1):

Did you check which php.ini is loaded with your PHP? Make php file and put phpinfo() in it, run it and check for "Loaded configuration file"

Did you restart webserver? Because php.ini is reloaded on webserver restart in Your case.

Is this class using https protocol? Then You need to uncomment openssl extension also.

Comment: It's definitely loading the right php.ini according to the loaded configuration file, and I definitely uncommented the right line.

Answer (score 0):

A good you to test your `PHP.INI` configuration in windows, is to run the PHP-CLI or check the log.

You can open the `cmd` and run the command `php` to see what's going on with your conf.